# C++ Friend Classes

Tags: c++, friend

Just trying to make sure I have understood friends properly with this one

```
class A
{
  friend class B;
  int valueOne;
  int valueTwo;
  public:
  int GetValueOne(){ return valueOne; }
}
class B
{
  public:
  A friendlyData;
  int GetValueTwo(){ return friendlyData.valueTwo; }
}
main()
{
  B myObject;
  myObject.friendlyData.GetValueOne(); // OK?
  myObject.GetValueTwo(); // OK?
}
```

In reference to that code about, if we ignore the lack of initialising, the two functions in main would OK right? And besides doing some funky stuff, their should be no other way to get the data from these classes... To the out side of these class, `B.A` has no accessible data, just the member function.

Comment: Never ever make any non-constant attributes public.

Comment: erm... care to explain what you mean by that lot?

Comment: Recheck your code... `B.A.GetValueOne()` is a compiler error. Did you mean to write `myObject.friendlyData.GetValueOne()`? The same goes for the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the two identified calls in `main` are OK.  They involve the access of 3 members: `B::A`, `B::GetValueTwo` and `A::GetValueOne`.  All of which have `public`accessibility and expose no privae types.  Hence they're usable from anywhere including `main`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks reasonable as both of the `GetValueX` methods are public and so the calls are fine. The call to `GetValueTwo()` call makes use of its friendship.

Word of warning: friendship can break the encapsulation in your design.

Comment: Or friendship can enhance encapsulation: http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093618/how-does-the-friend-keyword-class-function-break-encapsulation-in-c/1093681#1093681

Comment: Very true, I was trying to find a GoTW reference discussing the issue in more depth.

Comment: Friendship can also improve the encapsulation in your design.  It depends how you use it.

Comment: "friendship can break the encapsulation" -> according the Stroustrup, [it does not](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#friend).

Comment: Those references both argue in favour of "befriending" free functions, but they don't seem to be making a similar argument for class friendships.